# Identify traffic coming from social networks (facebook, twitter, google+)

Tags: php, httprequest, user-agent

What would be the best way, in PHP, to identify traffic coming to my platform from social networks such as Facebook, Twitter and Google+?

I suppose I could look at the HTTP_USER_AGENT, but then I need to know the HTTP_USER_AGENT for the social networks I would to identify. Is there a better way?

Basically want to do something if someone comes to my website from a social network referrer.

Comment: Try to use google analytics. See article http://marketingland.com/google-analytics-social-reports-8138

Comment: Browsers don't change the user agent based on the referrer. Why would they?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP user agent won't give you the information you're looking for.

I would check the HTTP_REFERER header:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Check if it contains the domain names you look for.

Comment: What sort of domains would I check?
facebook.com, plus.google.com, twitter.com? But that would leave out international versions of the sites. so would I leave out the .com part?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the domain structures will look in this case. I would probably leave out the TLD part (.com for example).